# Enterprise Library 5.0 - Adding custom tokens to a TextFormatter

Tags: logging, exception, enterprise-library

I have created a custom Exception that has data pertaining to our application.  I want to ensure this data gets logged when an exception is thrown and logged to the event log.

I have tried creating a custom TextFormatter which is being called but am not sure how to access the current exception so I can add our custom information to the log entry.

There is something I am not understanding and would appreciate any help around adding custom tokens (and data) to Enterprise Library 5.0 TextFormatters.

Thanks,
...Marc

Answer (score 2):

You could extend `TextFormatter`.  I think the issue there is that `TextFormatter` formats a `LogEntry`:

```cs
public override string Format(
    LogEntry log
)
```

So you need to get your custom data into the LogEntry.  (Which I think is what your question is asking.)

An alternative (and I think simpler) approach is to use the `ExtendedProperties` of `LogEntry`.  If you are using the Exception Handling Block (EHAB) to log your exception then you can add all of your custom information to the `IDictionary` `Data` property.  At runtime, the contents of the Data dictionary are added to the `ExtendedProperties`.  Specific properties can then be logged by using tokens in the formatter definition.

e.g.

```cs
public class MyException : Exception
{
    private string myCustomProperty;

    public string MyCustomProperty
    {
         get
         {
             return myCustomProperty;
         }
         set
         {
             myCustomProperty = value;
             Data["MyCustomProperty"] = value;
         }
    }
}
```

Then you can handle the exception using EHAB with a logging policy:

```cs
ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Logging Exception Handler");
```

In your template add something like the following:

MyCustomProperty: {keyvalue(MyCustomProperty)}

This will then log your custom property.

If you are not using EHAB then you could **not** set the Data value in your exception class and then create small helper class to add your custom property to the `ExtendedProperties`:

```cs
public void LogException(Exception ex)
{
    LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
    //...
    logEntry.ExtendedProperties.Add("MyCustomProperty", ex.MyCustomProperty);

    Logger.Write(logEntry);
}
```

If logging of custom exception properties is a general problem for you then you could add all of your custom properties to the Data dictionary and then in the helper method copy all of the Data key/value pairs to the ExtendedProperties.

Answer (score 1):

Lab2 of the [Extensibility Hands-On Labs](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=209184) provides step-by-step guidance on building custom tracelistener and text formatters.