# Custom tokens in Enterprise library logging using flat file listener and text formatter

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I am new to enterprise library.We are trying to log our application using enterprise library 5.0. We are using flat file listener method of logging and text formatter as log message formatter.

We want to log all our methods and method parameters. So we are writing a custom method and it will write the log entry.

So we want to create custom properties in LogEntry like its built in properties like Message, MachineName etc. ie we want properties like MethodName, Param1 etc. So that we can assign its values from our methods and can be written to the text file.

We can do this in Message, but instead we are trying to get custom properties.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745078/enterprise-library-5-0-adding-custom-tokens-to-a-textformatter). But I want properties like Message etc.